# ETPUSH addAttributes not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush

I'm using SDK in my android app, and I'm trying to set attributes (already created in MC) but MC never shows me value I set in my android app.

```
etPush.addAttribute("MunicipioResidencia","MunicipioResidencia");
etPush.addAttribute("TipoFamNumerosa","TipoFamNumerosa");
etPush.addAttribute("NumDocumentoFN","NumDocumentoFN");
```

I am currently doing that, however, in contact detail never is set this values:
[image: attribute empty]

How this is really working? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you provided.  How are you getting your instance of ETPush?  If you're getting it from the configureSdk() callback, are you checking for success?  What does the LogCat say regarding configuration success/failure?  What version of the SDK?

Comment: Thank you for answering. My version: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk:etsdk:4.7.1@aar' How long does it takes since I call this sentences and contact changes in MC? My LogCat seems to be ok https://pastebin.com/6Kgrh8bX I'm going to test that what you say about calling this inside configureSdk... but that is not make sense for me... I would like to set attributes whenever I want ... thank you!

Comment: There is a 15 min. propagation delay from the time the SDK transmits the Registration payload and the data being available throughout the Salesforce Cloud.  You _can_ set those values from anywhere in your code.  I was just curious as to whether or not you had verified that your Push Configuration was successful.

Comment: 15 minutes? i didn't read such a thing.. where did u read that? ty!

Comment: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/attributes.html the NOTE section.  I guess we're stating 5 min. these days, but 15 min. will be much more safe ;)